# Error inserting data into Microsoft access database from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I need to add data to a link table in microsoft access linking things entered into the other fields of the database. I can't see the error in my code but it doesnt add the data to the databse.

Please help

```
    Private Sub medication_input()
        Dim str As String
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim test As String
        Dim stop_loop As Boolean = False
        Do Until stop_loop = True
            str = "SELECT [Student ID] FROM [Student data] WHERE [Student First Name] = '" & Student_FN.Text & "' AND [Student Last Name] = '" & Student_LN.Text & "' AND [Form group] = '" & Form.SelectedItem & "';"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.Read Then
                test = reader("Student ID").ToString
            Else
                stop_loop = True
                'msgbox("error")
            End If
            cmd.Dispose()
            str = "Insert into [Student + Medication] ([Student ID],[Medical ID]) values(?,?)"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
            If Medication.SelectedItem = "Bricanul" Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Student ID", CType(test, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Medical ID", CType("1", String)))
            ElseIf Medication.SelectedItem = "Symbricort" Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Student ID", CType(test, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Medical ID", CType("2", String)))
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Student ID", CType(test, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Medical ID", CType("3", String)))
            End If
            cmd.Dispose()
            stop_loop = True
        Loop
    End Sub
```

This is a code i previously used to create a login form in which i have successfully saved data into the database.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter_button.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "
        datafile = "P:\Documents\SCHOOL WORK\A level\COMPUTER SCIENCE\PROJECT\Visual basic\Login.accdb"
        connstring = provider & datafile
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into Login ([username],[password]) values(?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("username", CType(Username.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("password", CType(hash(Password.Text), String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myconnection.Close()
            Username.Clear()
            Password.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't add data to the database. Exactly what line of that code do you think would do that?

Comment: Also, if you create a data reader then make sure that you close it when you're done with it.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Student ID", CType(test, String)))` has worked previously in my program.

Comment: How do i close the datareader

Comment: You are looking for the [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery).

Comment: *"...has worked previously in my program"*. No it hasn't. Well, it's worked to do what it does, i.e. add a parameter to a command. Adding a parameter to a command is not saving data though. If you have saved data successfully in other projects then you did something else as well in those projects.

Comment: *"How do i close the datareader"*. What information did you find on that when you searched the web and what don't you understand about it?

Comment: You created parameters, but never Executed.  Also, your loop will only move the first row. If you only want to move the first row, then you don't need a loop.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have updated my question to show code that has previously worked very well for me. I cant see the difference that could account for my mistake.

Comment: @tgolisch I have had this error for three days and thats all i have been doing to my entire project. I fixed a couple errors however am at a complete loss as to what i did wrong. I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions and answers however none seem to have helped.

Comment: So, you can't see any lines of code in that second snippet in between adding the parameters and disposing the command that are not also in the first snippet?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you so much for your help. I accidentally deleted that line of code. Sorry for wasting everyones time.

Comment: @ADyson I did im just dyslexic and it is sometimes tricky to distinguish the lines especially when i have been staring at the same screen for days on end

Comment: Well I'm sorry that's a problem for you, clearly it doesn't make things simple. But unfortunately programming is all about the small details. So you maybe need to think about finding some tools / techniques for your everyday programming which help you to work more efficiently in that respect. Good luck with your future projects.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. I try my hardest to not let it catch me out but sometimes it does. Ill try find other techniques to improve it.